# Application.MoveAfterReturn=False not working on protected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

To prevent the selection from moving away from the active cell after the user clicks return I included `Application.MoveAfterReturn = False` in a `Workbook_Open` procedure.

This works fine on unprotected sheets, but it does not work on protected sheets.
Is this by design, or is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Can you add more detail on how it doesn't work? I can get this to work on both protected and unprotected sheets.

Comment: Your Workbook_Open procedure probably sets the protection. You might set the protection after setting the Application property. You might also set the protection property `UserInterfaceOnly = True` so that your code has free access.

Comment: Agree with @BigBen. It works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my post of Jan-27 was kind of premature, because `Application.MoveAfterReturn = False` actually works for me too...

After some further testing it turned out that my problem is in fact limited to 1 (one) particular workbook only.

Essentially, the offending workbook is relatively simple, and with `Application.MoveAfterReturn` set to False the selection does indeed not move when pressing [enter/return] on an unprotected worksheet, as expected, but as soon as I protect the sheet and press [enter/return] the selection moves down to the next row.

**UPDATE Jan-30**

Whatever I tried, I really could NOT get this to work, and even now it remains quite puzzling why only the workbook in question manifests the described issue.

Finally however, considering that the relevant property does function properly in other workbooks,  I manually copied data and code to a new workbook, and lo and behold, `Application.MoveAfterReturn = False` now totally works as advertised, on unprotected AND on protected worksheets!

*The wonders of technology?*

Answer (score 0):

I'd been plagued by the same mystery recently and discovered the source of this issue.  It's also 100% reproducible as well.  Meaning that I can get MoveAfterReturn to work as expected or to fail (i.e. pressing return selects the next cell even with MoveOnReturn=False) merely by checking a single box.

If you want MoveOnReturn to "work" make certain that "Select Locked Cells" is checked in the Protect Worksheet options under the Review tab, or set it to True in the ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("...").Protect property.  If you do either, pressing enter will stop advancing to the next cell.  Uncheck "Select Locked Cells" or set the property to False, and the enter key will ignore whatever value MoveOnReturn is assigned and advance to the next cell.

I've tried this on several old workbooks that I could **never** get MoveOnReturn to work correctly and tried it on newly created workbooks as well.  All of them behaved as described.

Don't ask why this makes any sense.